# Fast texture pixel access using SDL2

Tags: sdl, sdl2

People have asked questions on fast pixel manipulation, but I'm looking to read the RGB color values of each pixel.

I've heard of `SDL_RenderReadPixels` but in the docs it says:

> WARNING: This is a very slow operation, and should not be used frequently.

Is there an SDL2 function that returns an array of all the pixels of a texture or an SDL2 routine that I can use to loop over each pixel?

Answer (score 5):

SDL2's "texture" rendering API is designed for accelerated graphics in mind; this is where you upload textures to your graphics hardware beforehand, and then render that texture by referring to it.

This is why textures are write-only, and can only be written to if:

- the texture was created with the `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING` flag
- you lock the texture before writing using [`SDL_LockTexture`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockTexture)

So if you want to do pixel manipulation, you should do it in-memory, using a plain pixel buffer (or sometimes an [`SDL_Surface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface)). Then when you're done, create a texture out of the buffer. If you do this repeatedly with the same texture, use a texture with the aforementioned `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING` flag. This is still very slow though because it's unaccelerated.

For efficient pixel manipulation, the standard practice is to write **shader code**.

Comment: I'm not looking to manipulate the pixels, just read them.

Comment: That is unfortunately also cataloged as manipulation. Data has to go back and forth between CPU and GPU. The GPU simply does not provide direct CPU access to its memory contents. It does not work that way.

Comment: @Viliami - it might be helpful if you said what you are actually trying to do rather than how you are trying to do it; i.e. *why* you are reading the pixels.  I say this because there may be another, more efficient, way of getting the same result.

Comment: @LeComteduMerde-fou I am comparing all the pixel values on the SDL window to an image, to see how similar the images are, used for something like this: https://rogeralsing.com/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/